# How to have an 'Other' row in a MySQL query to group less significant results

Tags: mysql

Take the following query. This fetches me the top 10 destinations by units sold, and that destination's share of total units sold across all destinations.

There are 124 individual results, however the share percentages of any below the top 10 are usually rather insignificant (less than 1%).

Is it possible to have a query, which will give the top 9 results by units, and then a 10th 'Other' row, which will summarize the rest of the results?

Or is this a 2 query job?

```
SELECT a.destination,
       SUM(a.units) AS units,
       SUM(a.units) / b.total * 100 AS `share`
    FROM range_data AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(units) AS total
                    FROM range_data) AS b
    GROUP BY a.destination
    ORDER BY units DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

**Current Result Set**

```
destination units   share
United Kingdom  433360  21.5943
Turkey  323657  16.1278
China   123264  6.1422
Russia  121595  6.0591
United States   106338  5.2988
Israel  97461   4.8565
Un Arab Emir    85221   4.2466
Egypt   51572   2.5698
Hong Kong   48932   2.4383
Suriname    44650   2.2249
```

**Desired Result Set**

```
destination units   share
United Kingdom  433360  21.5943
Turkey  323657  16.1278
China   123264  6.1422
Russia  121595  6.0591
United States   106338  5.2988
Israel  97461   4.8565
Un Arab Emir    85221   4.2466
Egypt   51572   2.5698
Hong Kong   48932   2.4383
Other   165854  8.8766
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You should be able to do that with `UNION` but it's very similar to run a second query, except for the php handling..

Comment: I don't understand how the final row relates to the result set

Comment: @Strawberry it is there purely just to illustrate - if you want to get pedantic about the content so you can justify your close vote then carry on.

Comment: What's it illustrating?

Comment: @Strawberry as said `a 10th 'Other' row, which will summarize the rest of the results`

Comment: You haven't, and I have removed any 'rude' remarks from my own comments. But your persistence in trying to make this question out to be non-sensical is rather annoying, given that the question title is probably enough to describe my issue.

Comment: You keep saying. I still don't understand what you're trying to do. I think it's some kind of aggregate but I don't know if it's an average or a sum or a standard deviation or whatever. You seem to think you have an answer, so great, let's leave it there - but we'll never know if there was a better solution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 2 query job, however you can combine the 2 queries into one using `union`. The 1st query would be the same as the original, just it will have a limit 9, instead of 10. The other query will sum all the others up:

```
(SELECT a.destination,
   SUM(a.units) AS units,
   SUM(a.units) / b.total * 100 AS `share`
FROM range_data AS a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(units) AS total
                FROM range_data) AS b
GROUP BY a.destination
ORDER BY units DESC
LIMIT 9)
UNION
(SELECT 'other',
   SUM(a.units) AS units,
   SUM(a.units) / b.total * 100 AS `share`
FROM range_data AS a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(units) AS total
                FROM range_data) AS b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.destination
           FROM range_data AS c
           GROUP BY c.destination
           ORDER BY SUM(c.units) DESC
           LIMIT 9) t ON a.destination=t.destination
WHERE t.destination IS NULL)
ORDER BY IF(destination='other',0,units) DESC
```

The last `order by` is there to ensure that the 'other' is displayed on the bottom of the list.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks very much for this.  Have never made a 'custom' row before. And didn't think it would be as simple as SEELCT 'other'.  Nice touch